# Memory Error while selecting in CakePHP

Tags: web-services, cakephp, memory-management

i've worked out a Webservice. With a MySQL-DB behind it.The webservice expect 3 Parameters. A "From"-Value a To-Value and  "fmt" as a format-value. Like this:

```
"...requests?from=2011-10-18 16:15:00&to=2013-03-19 16:30:00&fmt=csv"
```

What i get is

```
"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720
 bytes) in...".
```

I know what that means but i figured out the following.
Before my Select (to collect the Data i want to return) triggers i just spend about `2.75MByte` of the memory. My select finished and the memeory is about  `237,75MByte`. Well if there would be tons of data i would understand but at the end I create a csv-file which is just `8.1MByte` big. Is there anything i have to know about the select in Cake?

Code-Snipped:

```
$condition = array('conditions'=> array(
                         'created_at >= "'. $this->params['url']['from'].
                         '"AND created_at <="'. $this->params['url']['to'].'"'
                         )
                   );           
$this->output_data = $this->LogRequest->find('all', $condition);
```

Comment: I reckon you [read the CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the [`ContainableBehavior`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containable).

If so you should set recursive to -1 before executing the `find()`:

`$this->LogRequest->recursive = -1;`

Comment: I just use the Table-Model. You idea dont really help, just tried it but aint change anything. What are you mean with ContainableBehavior?

Comment: I have added a link to the documentation of `ContainableBehavior`. How many record does your log_requests table have?

Comment: its about 90.000 rows. But i have done this before in another Framework and there wasnt even a part of that memory-hunger.

Comment: Well, 90k rows is pretty much. CakePHP debug is also consuming a lot of memory. You should try to disable the debug for this action `Configure::write('debug', 0);` (or set it max on 1) before increasing the php memory limit.

Comment: Well I allready have switched off the debug. The Question is where is the differenz between my old Framework and Cake. What does Cake doing while selecting. I think the containableBehaivior you show first is for thsoe who have put in relations between the table but i just leave that out till now. So there cant be the problem of this. And if the output of the stream is just 8MByte big. Why my application spend like 30 times that much to select the data.

Comment: Are you executing any other queries in that action or in the `beforeFilter()` of that controller or in the `beforeFilter()` of the `AppController`? Which CakePHP version are you using?

Comment: I use Version 2.4. I have a before Filter but i just figure that out that just when the select triggers the memory consumtion switches.

Comment: "2013-03-19 14:56:00 Info: before select:4194304"
"2013-03-19 14:56:01 Info: after select:249298944"

Comment: Okay, so `beforeFilter()` is not doing anything else. What have you declared in your Model `/app/Model/LogRequest.php`?

Comment: nothing at all. Just a validation in the AppModel but i allready delete that and try again but nothing changed. Though there would be any problems doing the validation over and over again but it doesnt. Code Snippet: <?php 
class LogRequest extends AppModel {
 
 public $name = 'LogRequest';
}

?> just using the parent

Comment: Try to set the `'limit' => 100` on the `find()` action and debug `$this->output_data` to see what actually is being retrieved from the database

Comment: array(
 (int) 0 => array(
  'LogRequest' => array(
   'id' => '1860',
   'ip' => '196.99.236.161',
   'user_id' => null,
   'session_id' => null,
   'duration' => '150',
   'duration_backend' => null,
   'request' => '/bob/tagesgeldantrag/start',
   'response' => null,
   'parameter' => null,
   'err' => null,
   'created_at' => '2011-10-18 16:23:39'
  )
 ),......

Comment: i think this is correct. Ever Table with keys as colum and value as fields

Comment: Im sorry i can't help you further. I think CakePHP can not handle the 90k records at once, you should split the find() query in a couple steps.